# Can't play YouTube on mediaelement

Tags: c#, youtube, uwp, mediaelement

I have a mediaelement to play youtube with XAML and code below:
XAML:

```
<MediaElement AutoPlay="False" AreTransportControlsEnabled="True" IsFullWindow="False">
    <MediaElement.TransportControls>
        <MediaTransportControls IsFullWindowButtonVisible="True"/>
    </MediaElement.TransportControls>
</MediaElement>
```

Code:

```
VideoLink.Text = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QJ9h7EBs5LU";
string videoLink = VideoLink.Text.Substring(Math.Max(0, VideoLink.Text.Length - 11));

var url = await YouTube.GetVideoUriAsync(videoLink.ToString(), YouTubeQuality.Quality480P);
YoutubePlayer.Source = url.Uri;
YoutubePlayer.Play();
```

I'm having trouble, ie can not play youtube with error message like the image below:
[image: video error]

How to handle it?

Comment: can you share your code for GetYouTubeVideoURLAsync?

Comment: I tried the same, using the nugget. There seems to be some issue with the metadata of the video as all other videos are working perfectly fine and I did try using the embedded video as well

Comment: @AdityaSharma GetVideoUriAsync is a code from MyToolkit.Extended, so I only use the code: VideoLink.Text = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QJ9h7EBs5LU";
string videoLink = VideoLink.Text.Substring(Math.Max(0, VideoLink.Text.Length - 11));

var url = await YouTube.GetVideoUriAsync(videoLink.ToString(), YouTubeQuality.Quality480P);
YoutubePlayer.Source = url.Uri;
YoutubePlayer.Play();

Comment: as I said, there seems to be an issue with the meta data of the video that has been uploaded as when I used some other video URL it worked perfectly fine also, I was able to use the embedded youtube url to be used for other videos but the URL that you provided doesn't work with embedded link as well. It seems you should rather raise a question/issue at the github or nugget repository to the developer of the library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party .net library to extract the source url of a youtube video then put it into mediaelement.

https://github.com/flagbug/YoutubeExtractor

YoutubeExtractor is a great library but it can't parse the music section videos' source from Youtube.